# how to implement the code for fetching of image from google business api in a react native app

Tags: ios, react-native

It is fetching the reviews from the google reviews but someone put the image on the google reviews. How to fetch the image id or display the image on app

I tried same methods of fetching reviews but enable to do same with the google business image review.
I want to fetch the image id or same image in the react native app